# Different (dynamic) items height in GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, height, android-recyclerview, rows, gridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager with 2 columns.
How can I force LayoutManager to be according with template on the first screenshot? Now I have result as on the 2th screenshot.

Need result:

[image]

Current result:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`GridLayoutManager` will use a grid, and you can set some span, but not different heights for different cells.

What you want is a [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html). This will just put the items on the screen if they fit, leading to your needed result. You can also change the reordering behavior, if you want to, by using [`setGapStrategy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#setGapStrategy(int)).

Comment: "but not different heights for different cells." you can set different height of rows, though; for example each cell has image view with height set to wrap_content and different images are set in each cell then each row will take the height of the biggest images

Comment: how can i achieve horizontal dynamic size for vertical staggered grid layout items? or in other words, Suppose i have 2 columns in staggered grid layout. Can i change columns width dynamically?

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Try this [SpannableGridLayout Manager 1](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/commit/a14eb290a9ad80434e063a466ee82ad44d06950c#diff-1e986e17c47052bd2f89586e1f89f6ce) or this [SpannableGridLayout Manager 2](https://github.com/noowenz/SpannedGridLayoutManager)

Answer (score 9):

It's really easy. You have to add this manager to RecycleView:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(mColumnCount, 1));
```

in my case it's look like this:

```
Context context = view.getContext();
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;

if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
} else {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(mColumnCount, 1));
}
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, mListener));
```