# How to achieve a grid in which height is calculated row wise in Android?

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I have to make a `RecyclerView` like in the picture.
I have tried `GridLayoutManager` and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` but then always take up the height of the maximum height of the view in the array.

**Please suggest**

I am not adding any source code because it is pretty much one liner for a `layoutManager`

[image]

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/34978737/7666442 also check **[FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)**

Comment: First link i have. It does not solve my problem