# Different height in ConstraintLayout RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have this structure

```
RecyclerView
 - ConstraintLayout
 - - CardView
 - - - ConstraintLayout
 - - - - ImageView 
 - - - - TextView
 - - - - TextView
```

Code:

```
    vm = ViewModelProvider(this)[CatalogViewModel::class.java]
    vm.getList().observe(this, Observer {
        dataView = findViewById(R.id.dataList)
        adapter = CatalogRecycleViewAdapter(this, it.data.data)

        dataView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        dataView.adapter = adapter;
    })
```

And if I have 2 or more items width different height, there's an empty space in a column.

[image: If I have 2 or more items width different height there's an empty space in a column]

How to remove it and make something like in picture?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your TextView has wrap_content height, thats the reason one is bigger. Checkout this answer to get the result you are looking for [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978737/different-dynamic-items-height-in-gridlayoutmanager)